# Bootstrap IE10 UTF8 placeholders?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, utf-8, internet-explorer-10, placeholder

I try to insert utf8 text to a placeholder attribute on input field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="!עברית" />
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9XWD/2/)

It works fine on all browsers (IE8+), but on 2 machines running IE10 the text is displayed as squares, although the same code renders fine on another IE10 machine!

This is how it should look, and how it looks on these two machines:
[Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/qud5mi0kr/)

*(need 10 rep to post images..)*

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you setting the form to UTF "<form accept-charset='UTF8'>" ?

Comment: Yes, I removed it from the example for clarity. I also have meta tags with charset=UTF-8.